# Syntax error unexpected near ('

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I was creating table in hive with

```
create table stores(
    storeid integer,
    area string,
    city string,
    state string,
    country string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using INT in place of Integer.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied and pasted your ddl statement above into my hive cli and it worked perfectly.[image]

You need to check your hive installation

Answer (score 0):

INTEGER can be used from Hive version 2.2.0 onwards. For earlier versions, INT should be used.

Try using this DDL:

```
create table stores(
storeid int,
area string,
city string,
state string,
country string);
```

References: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-NumericTypes

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14950